# Need a fast algorithm of adaptive convolution

Tags: signal-processing, convolution, filters

Good morrow, gentlemen!

I have to apply some kind of adaptive filter to my function $f(x).$ I present each point of my signal as a Gaussian, whose bandwidth depends on its location **(not the point of observation $\textbf{x}$)** as $h(t),$ which is a known pre-calculated function. The final output function $s(x)$ is a superposition of the influence of all gaussians (of all points).

$$s(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)g(h(t),x-t)dt$$

$g(h(t),x)$ is a $NormPDF(\sigma, x_0, x)$ with $\sigma=h(t)$, $x_0=0$

It gives a good look of $s(x)$, but is calculates a bit too slow.

If I had a fixed-bandwidth filter, I could perform the well-known fast convolution algorithm via FFT. Or I could drop the faraway points and have the convolution as:
$$s(x)=\int\limits_{x-\Delta x}^{x+\Delta x}f(t)g(h(t),x-t)dt$$

But for the adaptive filter I should take my $\Delta x$ at least twice as large, as the maximum bandwidth is (in my case it is nearly 30% of all x area), so it cannot give a big profit.

Also, I don't know any algorithms of fast convolutions for such types of filters.

Cannot you help me, if you know something about them?

Comment: It should be $g(h(x), x - t))$ in the integral right?  So for each $x$ a strictly Gaussian kernel but with diameter depending on $x$?

Comment: No, the diameter of each gaussian depends on the location of each gaussian $t$, not on the location of observation point $x$.

Comment: You may want to try also posting this at dsp.stackexchange.com to better your chances of a solution.